# Turning an outer apply into a left join when you reference parent aliases

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm currently trying to turn an outer apply into a left join to save some complexity.

```
SELECT *
FROM fact_table h
     OUTER APPLY (SELECT TOP 1
                         *
                  FROM dimension mcc WITH (NOLOCK)
                  WHERE h.product = mcc.product
                    AND h.country = mcc.country
                    AND mcc.date IN (SELECT MAX(date)
                                     FROM dimension dd WITH (NOLOCK)
                                     WHERE FORMAT(DATEADD(MONTH, -3, dd.date), 'yyyyMM') <= h.month_in_the_year
                                       AND dd.product = h.product
                                       AND dd.country = h.country)) a;
```

I basically use it to get the related data from Dimension linked with the latest data point that's earlier than 3 months ago.

I'm trying to turn it into a left join, but it's taking a lot more time since I don't filter the dimension before the join :

```
SELECT TOP 10
       *
FROM fact_table h
     LEFT JOIN dimension a ON h.product = a.product
                          AND h.country = a.country
                          AND a.pkid = (SELECT TOP 1
                                               pkid
                                        FROM dimension dd
                                        WHERE FORMAT(DATEADD(MONTH, -3, dd.date), 'yyyyMM') <= h.month_in_the_year
                                        ORDER BY date DESC);
```

Do you have an idea on how to turn it efficiently into a left join ?

Comment: Based on the syntax, and the use of [[tag:tsql]] I *assume* this is [[tag:sql-server]]. Please don't tag conflicting tags unless the question is *really* about both products. If this is about [[tag:mysql]] as well, then [edit] your question appropriately.

Comment: A query with a `TOP` and no `ORDER BY` always has a "code smell" to it; the result you get are going to be arbitrary *every* time you run the query and thus could be completely different every time you run it too.

Comment: `FORMAT(DATEADD(MONTH, -3, dd.date), 'yyyyMM') <= h.month_in_the_year` is *not* going to be any good for performance. `FORMAT` is notoriously slow, and putting that in a `WHERE` is going to be far from SARGable. Why are you converting a date to a `varchar` in the first place?

Comment: Yes, I would change `WHERE FORMAT(DATEADD(MONTH, -3, dd.date), 'yyyyMM') <= h.month_in_the_year` to equivalent logic that doesn't translate the search column, probably something like (untested!) `WHERE dd.date < DATEADD(MONTH, 2, DATEFROMPARTS(LEFT(h.month_in_the_year,4), RIGHT(h.month_in_the_year,2), 1))`, which should perform much better (especially with a usable index on the `date` column).

Comment: Though, that's not going to solve _obvious, observable_ performance differences between these two queries. To help with that, you'll need to provide table structure, indexes, sample data, and the execution plan that's slow. Can you capture an actual plan with [Plan Explorer](https://www.sentryone.com/plan-explorer) and post the .queryanalysis file somewhere? Or at least the .sqlplan to [PasteThePlan](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/)?

Comment: @Larnu my bad, thanks for the heads up about the etiquette I'll be sure to keep that in mind. And indeed thanks to your and Aaron Bertrand's answers it does run much faster, though the result isn't exactly the same so I'll check out why that is from the new formula. Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you can significantly simplify this query, by simply adding an `ORDER BY`. I've also modified the date filter in order to leverage indexing properly.

```sql
SELECT *
FROM fact_table h
OUTER APPLY (
    SELECT TOP 1 *
    FROM dimension mcc
    WHERE h.product = mcc.product
      AND h.country = mcc.country
      AND mcc.date < DATEADD(MONTH, 2, DATEFROMPARTS(LEFT(h.month_in_the_year, 4), RIGHT(h.month_in_the_year, 2), 1))
    ORDER BY mcc.date DESC
) a;
```

To transform this into a `LEFT JOIN`, you need to utilize row-numbering

```sql
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT *,
      rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY h.PrimaryKeyColumn ORDER BY mcc.date)
    FROM fact_table h
    LEFT JOIN dimension mcc
      ON h.product = mcc.product
        AND h.country = mcc.country
        AND mcc.date < DATEADD(MONTH, 2, DATEFROMPARTS(LEFT(h.month_in_the_year, 4), RIGHT(h.month_in_the_year, 2), 1))
) a
WHERE rn = 1;
```